Does employment notice period have to be equal + opposite? (UK)
I took a contract role inside IR35.
When signing the contract, I noticed that the employer's notice period was 2 weeks, but the worker's notice period was 4 weeks. I said I wanted these periods to be equal + opposite.
The response I got was that the contract had been worked out at a corporate level way above everyone's paid grade, by their USA HQ, using USA lawyers. To protest this one point of the contract would throw a spanner in the works, and for the sake of speed in filling the role, they'd probably look for another candidate. With the job market in my industry being as dry as 2008 after Lehman collapsed, I signed and took the role.
Under UK law (England & Wales) is this clause enforceable?
What might or could happen if I gave 2 weeks notice and then simply departed?

in UK there is a statutory minimum notice period given by the employer, based on length of service. After two years, the contract would be in breach of the law. However the employee's notice required can be more than the statutory minimum, and you accept the job on these terms. What happens when you break the contract? Ask your employer!

...but under IR35 I don't think there are statutory notice periods, only contractual. But nobody can say what action the employer would take if you break the contract. Who knows? They might suffer loss of business and sue you.
